# Jquery plugin for getting changes in textarea and sending them to server

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I am getting a file "abc.txt" from server and dispaying it in a text area for editing.

```
<div id="filecontents"> <textarea>  CONTENTS OF FILE LARGER THAN 10KB
 </textarea> </div>
```

The contents of the file are potentially large. The user will edit the textarea and add/delete text from any part(not just the end). I want to send ONLY the changes to the server for patching. How do I accomplish this?. Is there a javascript version of the popular linux command(diff). John Resig's diff code may not work as, for me, it will involve additional parsing on server side.

Thanks!

Comment: why not just replace the whole thing? Processing the new sting against the old string would be slower and more resource intensive than just doing a replacement.

Comment: Lets say that you do this diff in Javascript... You send up only the changes. Now what? How do you know where these changes are? How are you going to make the changes where they need to be? It would be easier, mind you it would use more bandwidth, and less computational power to just send the entire file back up... Sounds like you should invest some time to learning to use something like git, and introduce it to whomever this thing is targeted at.

Comment: @Dagon, I understand that the processing can be resource intensive. But the changes are small typo changes. So I think client can handle it.

Comment: @Justin, change information must also contain where information also!

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [google-diff-match-patch](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/), it looks like it should do what you want.

Comment: @ultranut, This looks like what I am looking for. I will use it and let you know the performance.